# toBuilder() vs Setter in database

Tags: java, hibernate, lombok

I am trying to save data in database with OneToOne mapping in bidirectional way. I have used toBuilder and setter and got different result in Database.
By using setter:

```
        Question question = Question.builder().quest("What is Pythonn ?").answer(null).build();
        Answer answer = Answer.builder().answer("Python is language").que(question).build();
        answer.setQue(question);
        question.setAnswer(answer);
        Question question2 = Question.builder().quest("How are you ?").answer(null).build();
        Answer answer2 = Answer.builder().answer("I am fine").build();
        answer2.setQue(question2);
        question2.setAnswer(answer2);
        session.save(question);
        session.save(question2);
```

the result in db

[question_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3eF2.png)

[Answer table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoOKn.png)

By using toBuilder

```
 answer.toBuilder().que(question).build();
 question = question.toBuilder().answer(answer).build();
 answer2.toBuilder().que(question2).build();
 question2 = question.toBuilder().answer(answer2).build();
```

The result in db:
[question_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYjnG.png)

[answer_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZiv3.png)

Why toBuilder is not working while setter is working ?

Comment: Please add the source code of the Question and Answer class including the Lombok and Hibernate annotations.

Comment: Also, you don't save the result from the build() calls for answer and answer2.

Answer (score 1):

You don't save a reference to question2 in answer2. That's why answer 2 has a null value for the question column.

```java
Answer answer2 = Answer.builder().answer("I am fine").build();
 answer2.toBuilder().que(question2).build();
```

And you use question in the builder for question2. That's why there are multiple entries for question 1.

```java
question2 = question.toBuilder().answer(answer2).build();
```

As for first question row with a null value for answer, I'm not sure where that's coming from.